# Preencher um documento Word a partir do Delphi

Tags: delphi, microsoft-word

Quero criar um sistema em `Delphi`, onde eu preencho as `labels` e após cria um documento no word com as informações que eu digitei...

Coloquei um exemplo abaixo onde eu vou digitar as informações e quando eu gerar ele vai jogar essas informações em um documento do Word

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: @user8626 : Seja bem-vindo ao SOpt. Sugiro uma lida neste link para poder melhorar sua pergunta: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . Depois de dar uma lida, pode clicar em "editar" logo abaixo da sua pergunta para acrescentar mais detalhes.

Comment: Bom dia Anderson. Se a resposta do @Caputo responde sua questão peço que por favor a aceite para que esta não conste como sem resposta. Caso não responda, por favor, informe mais detalhes do que realmente quer para que uma resposta possa surgir.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Uma das maneiras mais fáceis de se integrar o `Delphi` com o `Word` é através de um `OleObject`, mas tenha em mente que se na máquina que for executar o aplicativo, se o `Word`não estiver instalado, vai gerar uma `EOleException` de Classe não registrada.

```
function PreencherDadosArquivo(const NomeArquivo: string): Boolean; 
var 
  WordApp: Variant;
  Documento: Olevariant;
begin 
  WordApp:= CreateOleObject('Word.Application'); 
  try 
    WordApp.Visible := False;
    Documento := WordApp.Documents.Open(NomeArquivo);

    Documento.Content.Find.Execute(FindText := '[Nome]', ReplaceWith := edtNome.Text); 
    Documento.Content.Find.Execute(FindText := '[Sobrenome]', ReplaceWith := edtSobreNome.Text); 
    Documento.Content.Find.Execute(FindText := '[Endereco]', ReplaceWith := edtEnd.Text); 
    Documento.Content.Find.Execute(FindText := '[Telefone]', ReplaceWith := edtTel.Text); 

    Documento.SaveAs('SeuNovoNomeArquivo.doc')
  finally
    WordApp.Quit;
  end;
end;
```

Mas para fazer desta forma o seu documento deveria estar da seguinte forma, e lembrando de colocar o nome dos objetos `TEdit` para os seus do seu formulário:

```
|Nome   |   Sobrenome   |   Endereco    |  Telefone    |  
--------------------------------------------------------  
|[Nome] |   [Sobrenome] |   [Endereco]  |  [Telefone]  |
```

Answer (score 1):

Uma maneira simples também seria gerar a relação em PDF, através de um quickreport por exemplo e instalar um impressora virtual, que quando for "imprimir" salva em doc do word.